# problems on importing csv data into mysql using pymysql

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I am new to sql and python, and i am currently working on a project to import csv data into mysql using pymysql. The table name in sql is pythontable. The csv file has 5 columns with cusip, permno, permco, issuno, hexcd and its corresponding values. 
However, my code is not working. please help.

```
import csv 
import pymysql


mydb = pymysql.connect( host = 'ip' ,  user ='user' ,  passwd = "pw" , db = "db")  
cursor = mydb.cursor() 
csv_data = csv.reader('data.csv')

for row in csv_data:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO pythontable(cusip, permno, permco, issuno, hexcd)' 'VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', row)

mydb.commit() 
cursor.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that columns and data type in columns match in MySQL table and CSV file.

You can execute the query as following then:

```
 cursor.execute('INSERT INTO pythontable VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', row)
```